# SharePoint Online Modern List column names empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience

I'm in the middle of creating new lists. Some for net new creation, others to simplify my migration process from '07 to Online. (I use ShareGate, and going from classic lists to modern lists is not 100%, this is the workaround I found.)

So I'm working on a brand new list for a team, and have the thing ready to start building views.

But when I create a new view, I get blank column headers. This is whether I go into list settings and create a view, or use the `+ Add column -> Show/hide columns` feature in the Modern UI. It doesn't do it for every column either.
[image: Working Columns][image: Adding Column]
[image: Empty Columns]

And the strange part is when I edit in the Modern UI, I get the Column Internal Names for only the columns selected.

[image]

I have had one site get over this after some time, making me think it might be due to the Tenant crawl, but I am unsure.

Has anyone else had this experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online, the column header can display normally in the modern list.

Did the issue only occur in one site?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Create a new site to check if the same issue will occur.
2. Switch to classic experience to check if the same issue will occur.
3. Switch to other browsers to check if the same issue will occur.